# Node.js List All Modules Required in a File

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I must be missing something here. I have a mocha test file that is set up like so:

```
require('globals');
var library1 = require('library1'),
  library2 = require('library2');

it('tests stuff', function() {
  ...
});
```

Where the `globals` file just contains a `before` and `afterEach` block, so that they apply to all my test files.

What I'm trying to do is determine, within the `before` and `afterEach` blocks, which files that I have `require`'d in the test file that those blocks are currently running in. So in the example test file I gave, I would need `afterEach` to output a list that contains `globals`, `library1`, and `library2`.

I have attempted to use Node.js's `module.children` property, but for some reason that is only returning me `globals`, and excluding `library1` and `library2`.

**Edit:** What am I missing that `module.children` wouldn't be returning `library1` and `library2`?

Comment: Did you try require.cache https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache?

Comment: I did try that, but it gives me a list of **everything** that's been `require`'d, not just for that specific file, so it isn't very useful for me.

Comment: You could just parse the file and look for require statements and and copy whats in between the the parentheses

Comment: Is there something else you're trying to do that requires you to know what files have been required?

Comment: I have custom libraries that I'm including in my tests. Based on which test files include which library, I want to do certain clean up actions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a script that will parse requires in a file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function parseRequires(absPath){
    var requiredFiles = [];
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(absPath, 'utf8').split('\n');

    contents.forEach(function(line){
        var re = /(?:require\('?"?)(.*?)(?:'?"?\))/;
        var matches = re.exec(line);

        if(matches){
            requiredFiles.push(matches[1]);
        }

    });

    return requiredFiles;

}

module.exports = parseRequires;
```

I made a test script in the same directory

```
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

function A(){}

var http = require("http");

var parseRequires = require("./parseRequires");

console.log( parseRequires( __dirname + '/testRequires.js') );
```

results in console: `[ 'fs', 'os', 'http', './parseRequires' ]`

This is one solution, though I'm sure there is an easier way to do it with nodejs built in functionality

Comment: Thanks for this! I may have to resort to this, but I'm mostly curious as to why `module.children` isn't including the `require`'s that I've put into variables.

Comment: @RJMcdonald did this help you in the end or did you find a better solution? If so please post it

Comment: I have been unable to find a better solution. `module.children` should be returning all the requires, but for some reason it doesn't like the ones that are set to variables, so I'm hoping someone will enlighten me as to what I'm missing there.

Comment: @RJMcDonald I can only seem to get the non nodejs builtins to show up. are those a requirement?

Comment: I'm not interested in nodejs builtins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution I came up with using require.cache. It involves parsing require.cache for the files that have been required and provides the name of the file that ends up being required

```
var someModule = require('./someModule');
var path = require('path');
for( var p in require.cache){
  console.log( trim( p ) );
}

function trim(p){
  var re = /(.*?).js/;
  var basename = path.basename( p );
  var moduleName = re.exec( basename )[1];
  return moduleName; 
}
```

Test files:

someModule.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var _ = require('lodash');
var test = require('./test');
```

test.js

```
var a = require('lodash'),
jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Running getRequires.js results in

```
getRequires
someModule
index
test
jquery
```

Notice that it includes itself, so there would have to be something that trims that out as well.

Also notice index, that comes from lodash

Here is a modification that shows the file paths as well

```
var someModule = require('./someModule');
var path = require('path');
for( var p in require.cache){
  console.log( trim( p ) );
}

function trim(p){
  var re = /(.*?).js/;
  var basename = path.basename( p );
  var moduleName = re.exec( basename )[1];
  return [ moduleName, p ]; 
}
```

That gets us:

```
[ 'getRequires',
  '/<myroot>/require/getRequires.js' ]

[ 'someModule',
  '/<myroot>/require/someModule.js' ]

[ 'index',
  '/<myroot>/require/node_modules/lodash/index.js' ]

[ 'test', '/<myroot>/require/test.js' ]

[ 'jquery',
  '/<myroot>/require/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' ]
```

require is the directory I'm doing the code in.

Let me know about your thoughts on this solutions. There is more to be done but I think this can get you started.